# Hide/Show Content Based On Dropdown Selection

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

How can I make the content change based on the dropdown selection in this specific example?

Here is what I have tried:

```
  <select class="selection-of-areas" id="selection-of-area" onchange="changeFunc();">
<option value="illinois">Illinois</option>
<option value="florida">Florida</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="members-row illinois-members">
 Test Illinois
</div>

<div class="members-row florida-members">
Test Florida
</div>
```

And the js...

```
function changeFunc() {
    var selectBox = document.getElementById("selection-of-area");
    var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
   }


(function($) {
  $('.select-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
      $targetRow = $this.data('target'),
      $activeClassText = 'active';
    $('.select-button').removeClass($activeClassText);
    $this.addClass($activeClassText);
    $('.members-row').removeClass($activeClassText);
    $('.' + $targetRow + '-members').addClass($activeClassText);
  });
})(jQuery)
```

And the CSS:

```
.selection-of-areas {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #eee;
    padding: 11px 9px 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(120,120,120,.5);
}

.select-area-selection {
    display: block;
}

.members-row.active {
    display: block;
}

.members-row {
    display: none;
}
```

I created a codepen here:
https://codepen.io/gpercifield/pen/MWyKYeG

It just doesn't seem to fire at all.  Thank you for any help in pointing me the right direction.

Comment: Your `changeFunc()` does fire, but you do nothing with the `selectedValue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only one function that can fire on a change of dropdown.

```
function changeFunc(event) {
var selectBox = document.getElementById("selection-of-area");
var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;console.log(selectedValue)


// get the value
var activeClassText = 'active';
  $('.members-row').removeClass(activeClassText); // hide others
  $("."+selectedValue+'-members').addClass(activeClassText); // show only which is selected

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
$('.members-row').hide();
$('.' + selectedValue +'-members').show();
```

If you want it in javascript:

```
var hideele = document.querySelectorAll('.members-row');
for (var i = 0; i < hideele.length; i++) {
  hideele[i].style.display = 'none';
}
document.querySelectorAll('.' + selectedValue + '-members')[0].style.display = 'block';
```

**Demo**

```js
function changeFunc() {
  var selectBox = document.getElementById("selection-of-area");
  var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
  $('.members-row').hide();
  $('.' + selectedValue +'-members').show();
}
```

```css
.selection-of-areas {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 11px 9px 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(120, 120, 120, .5);
}

.select-area-selection {
  display: block;
}

.members-row.active {
  display: block;
}

.members-row {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selection-of-areas" id="selection-of-area" onchange="changeFunc();">
  <option value="illinois">Illinois</option>
  <option value="florida">Florida</option>
</select>


<div class="members-row illinois-members">
  Test Illinois
</div>

<div class="members-row florida-members">
  Test Florida
</div>
```